# Oracle . Limit number of rows in an entity

Tags: oracle

I want to limit number of rows in my entity . 
For example I had created a table family(id,name) and I want that no more than 5 rows can be inserted in family table. 
Any one with the suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For constraints on aggregates or data from multiple tables a helper `MATERIALIZED VIEW` can be created:

```
HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> CREATE TABLE family (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(255));

Table created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON family WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

Materialized view log created.

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW family_count
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS SELECT count(*) family_count FROM family;

Materialized view created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW family_count ADD CONSTRAINT max_family_count CHECK (family_count <= 5);

Materialized view altered.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> INSERT INTO family (id, name) values (1, 'Family 1');

1 row created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> INSERT INTO family (id, name) values (2, 'Family 2');

1 row created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> INSERT INTO family (id, name) values (3, 'Family 3');

1 row created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> INSERT INTO family (id, name) values (4, 'Family 4');

1 row created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> INSERT INTO family (id, name) values (5, 'Family 5');

1 row created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> INSERT INTO family (id, name) values (6, 'Family 6');

1 row created.

HUSQVIK@HQ_PDB_TCP> COMMIT;
COMMIT
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12008: error in materialized view refresh path
ORA-02290: check constraint (HUSQVIK.MAX_FAMILY_COUNT) violated
```